# How to get the innerHTML inside the anchor tags which retrieves only content not the tags within?

Tags: javascript, anchor

I want to retrieve the anchor tag content

```
<a id="1"><span class="italic">Hello There It Is Italic Text</span></a>
```

however when I use the following JS code

```
var resultData = document.getElementById("1").inneHTML;
console.log(resultData);
```

what I will get is

```
<span class="italic">Hello There It Is Italic Text</span>
```

as the resultData

where as I want the resultData to be "**Hello There It Is Italic Text**"
because I wannna use the resultData somewhere else

there are even some cases where there may be multiple span tags such as

```
<a id="2"><span class="italic"><span class="highlight">Hello There It Is Italic Text</span></span></a>
```

or

```
<a id="3"><span class="italic">Hello There It Is <span class="highlight">Italic</span> Text</span></a>
```

So I want the resultData to be "Hello There It Is Italic" in all the cases.
What I want is the **pure content of the anchor tag without any child tag**.

Can this be achieved using **pure Javascript** if yes how

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get **[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** property of the element.

```js
console.log(
  document.getElementById('1').textContent,
  document.getElementById('2').textContent,
  document.getElementById('3').textContent
)
```

```html
<a id="1"><span class="italic">Hello There It Is Italic Text</span></a>
<a id="2"><span class="italic"><span class="highlight">Hello There It Is Italic Text</span></span></a>
<a id="3"><span class="italic">Hello There It Is <span class="highlight">Italic</span> Text</span></a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you really saved my day

Comment: @KaranParikh : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve text rather than the entire markup, you should use `textContent`, not `innerHTML`.